# Where can I find documentation on Sharepoints backend Databases?

Tags: sql-server, database, sharepoint

When I look at the SQL Server my SharePoint site is using I see several databases in there that all appear to be used by my site.  Is there somewhere to find documentation on what each database stores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For info on what each database has try here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678868.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here's the MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998452.aspx

It comes with this Microsoft warning:

> **Warning**:  Modifying the database schema
>   or database structures is not
>   supported. Changes that you make to
>   the database contents may be
>   overwritten when you install updates
>   or service packs for Windows
>   SharePoint Services, or when you
>   upgrade an installation to the next
>   product version.

SharePoint comes with a rich set of APIs that may be better to use than connecting directly to the database.  [The Microsoft Develper center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905503) is a good starting point for working with MOSS APIs

Comment: That's very close.  I'm looking for something that is at the server level and offers descriptions for the databases on the server rather than at the database level and giving descriptions of the tables.

Comment: FYI I have no intention of modifying the DB.  I just want to know what goes where.